# WordPress: Adding home page (=latest posts page) to navigation properly

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress template displaying the latest posts on the home page (www.mydomain.bla) as it is the default setting in WordPress:

[image]

Now, I want to add a link referring to my home page in my navigation (with Appearance -> Menus). The only way I found to do this is by adding a custom link referring to my domain.

[image]

Here's my problem:

Even though the link itself does the job, one thing is not working. When navigating to a single post (like www.mydomain.bla/a-single-post) the needed classes indicating the parent link (***current-post-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent***) do not appear to a custom link like they would to if I had a "Post page" which is not the Homepage.

Is there a way to add a link referring to my posts-showing homepage properly?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new template named "Our blog" and paste the code for posts in this template. Now add a new page named "HOME", select OUR BLOG template and publish the page. Now go to the reading section under the setting tab and change the setting from your latest posts to a single page and select your HOME page. 
Now you can add page rather than adding a custom link in the menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Even though it seems to be a working workaround, I'm a bit confused there is possibly no simple solution to add a simple "Home" menu item to the navigation.

Comment: index.php is your default page for your posts, simply create a new page and assign index template (default template). add a page in your navigation menu under appearance > menu